# get attibute of xml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I know this is close to a duplicate but it isn't working for me and i dont know why

Heres my code

```
  children.css('tickets').each do |t|
        byebug
        each_ticket = {
          'ticket_id' => t.children.css('ticket')['id'],
          'faceValue' => t.children.css('faceValue').inner_text,
        }
        byebug
        ticket.push(each_ticket)
      end
```

Now if i type t in my byebug i get this back:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff310c5c4a0 name="tickets" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff313f4a1dc "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff313f4a038 name="ticket" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff313f4a830 name="id" value="370519">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff313f51be4 "\n          ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff313f51b30 name="name" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::CDATA:0x3ff313f5193c "Advance Discount Ticket">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff313f51770 "\n          ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff313f51694 name="faceValue" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff313f51464 "4.00">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff313f5125c "\n          ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff313f51180 name="bookingFee" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff313f50f8c "1.00">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff313f50dc0 "\n          ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff313f50d0c name="quantity" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff313f50af0 "More than 10 available">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff313f5094c "\n          ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff313f50884 name="status" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff313f50820 name="statuscode" value="1">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff313f503c0 "Available">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff313f50208 "\n        ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff313f50050 "\n      ">]>
```

What im wanting is the ID of the ticket. This is what i've tried

```
t.children.css('ticket').attribute('value')
```

And i keep getting nil returned

Any ideas?

Comment: can you attach your xml?

Comment: xml.skiddlecdn.co.uk/affiliates/all.xml